# Postfix + psql (Authenticate issues)

Tags: postgresql, email, postfix-mta

I´m having issues with a postfix server configuration and can´t find a answer

I´m setting a mail server, for that im using postfix like controller and postgresql to save user data, i can run all the server configuration except the connection by pgsql.

The user for connect to database is "app_postfix" and as pass "ab_cd" (Is not real the password)

My configuration with postgres at file pg_hba.conf is the next one:

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                peer

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
host    email           app_postfix     127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    email           app_courier     127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    email           app_sasl        127.0.0.1/32            md5

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#local   replication     postgres                                peer
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            md5
#host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 md5
```

Y para la conexión con la base de datos realizo lo siguiente, en el archivo de postfix:
And for the connection with the Database i use this at main.cf:

```
virtual_mailbox_maps = pgsql:/etc/postfix/db/users.cf
virtual_maps = pgsql:/etc/postfix/db/aliases.cf
```

aliases.cf:

```
#hosts = 127.0.0.1
user = app_postfix
password = ab_cd
dbname = email
query = SELECT "email_local" FROM users_aliases WHERE "email_alias" = '%s'
```

users.cf:

```
#hosts = 127.0.0.1
user = app_postfix
password = ab_cd
dbname = email
query = SELECT "path_maildir" FROM users WHERE "email_local" = '%s' AND "user_active" = '1'
```

The error code is this one:

```
warning: connect to pgsql server localhost: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "app_postfix"?FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "app_postfix"?
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why is the `hosts` entry commented?

Answer (score 0):

Try not to use special chars like #,$,!,(,) in your password.

When I couldn't connect postfix to postgres the only solution I found was removing special chars from my password.